# Generate all possible combinations

Tags: php, arrays, combinations

I have an app where users can customize the product they are going to purchase by choosing options from a menu. This menu has many sections, and each section may have a list of checkboxes for multichoice, or radiobuttons when only one option can be selected. The user must select at least one option in each section. The menu structure is something like this:

```
$sections = array();

$sections[1] = array(
    'multichoice' => true,
    'options' => array('A','B','C')
);

$sections[2] = array(
    'multichoice' => false,
    'options' => array('A','B','C','D')
);

$sections[3] = array(
    'multichoice' => false,
    'options' => array('A','B')
);

$sections[4] = array(
    'multichoice' => true,
    'options' => array('A','B','C','D','E')
);
```

Example: Sandwich is the product. Type of bread is one "section" of choice. You may want light bread, dark bread, milk bread or vegan bread. Only one option can be chosen under this section. Now in the "salad" section, you may choose more than one type of salad to add to the bread.

Now, my boss asked for me to create a page listing all possible combinations in case the user is too lazy to build the product himself. So I must be able to generate a structure like this:

```
$combinations = array(
    array(
        1 => array('A','B'),
        2 => 'A',
        3 => 'A',
        4 => array('B','D','E')
    ),
    array(
        1 => array('A'),
        2 => 'B',
        3 => 'A',
        4 => array('A','B')
    )
// etc...
);
```

I have managed to find all possible combinations using a random approach, generating hashes for comparision with what has already been generated. This actually works, but runs very slowly (this is brute-force basically):

```
...

function generate(){
    $result = array();
    $ids = array();
    foreach($this->getSections() as $sect){
        $items = $this->getSectionOptions($sect['id']);
        if($sect['multi']=='N'){
            $item = $items[rand(0, count($items)-1)];
            $result[$sect['id']] = $item['id'];
            $ids[] = $item['id'];
        } else {
            $how_many = rand(1,count($items));
            shuffle($items);
            for($i=1;$i<=$how_many;$i++){
                $item = array_shift($items);
                $result[$sect['id']][] = $item['id'];
                $ids[] = $item['id'];
            }
        }
    }
    sort($ids);
    return array(
        'hash' => implode(',',$ids),
        'items' => $result
    );
}

function generateMany($attempts=1000){
    $result = array();
    $hashes = array();
    for($i=1;$i<=$attempts;$i++){
        $combine = $this->generate();
        if(!in_array($combine['hash'],$hashes)){
            $result[] = $combine['items'];
            $hashes[] = $combine['hash'];
        }
    }
    return $result;
}


...
```

I want your help to create something more precise and faster. Remember that each combination must have at least one option of each section. And also keep in mind that the order of options in multichoice sections is irrelevant, (i.e. E,B,A is the same as B,E,A)

Thanks

Comment: I'm kind of lost, how did you make those combinations?

Comment: **1)** what does multichoice defines?

Comment: **2)** can you explain the logic of your combinations a bit clearer? I've got confused, made no sense to me

Comment: @XicoXperto the array of combinations I provided is just an example of  two unique combinations that are possible. I want the array to have all possible combinations.

Comment: @AlanMachado 1) multichoice defines the possibility of more than one option to be selected inside that section.

Comment: Assuming fewer combinations than I should, with these sections and options, the user has more than 5k possible outcomes. Is that better than building the project from scratch? Also, is the **order INSIDE same section** relevant? or for `section 4`, options `A,B,E` is **different** from `E,A,B`? @fabio

Comment: I disagree with you based on your own code example. `$sections[2]`, `$sections[3]` and `$sections[4]` have `multichoice` set to `false` and yet `options` has multiple combinations.

Comment: 2) Example: Sandwich is the product. Type of bread is one "section" of choice. You may want light bread, dark bread, milk bread or vegan bread. Only one option can be chosen under this section. Now in the "salad" section, you may choose more than one type of salad to add to the bread. I want to be able to construct all possible sandwiches.

Comment: Ooooh now I see! I suggest you edit your question after your first code block and add this comment, it's valuable information for people to help you easier.

Comment: @FirstOne No, the order is not relevant. The idea is the user can then order by price and take the lower price combination, or search for all combinations that have one specific "feature" and then buy the cheapest one.

Comment: @FirstOne just to make clear: A,B,E is NOT different from E,A,B (in the same section). The order is irrelevant

Comment: Is it necessary to have at least one option of each section?.. your examples suggest it is.

Comment: @AlvaroFlañoLarrondo Yes, it s necessary to have at least one option from each section.

Comment: Please add that restriction too to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Thanks this was a puzzle really fun to do!**

So how did I solve, recursion recursion recursion :D

I've started with the multi choice since it is the hardest one! (and actually it will solve also the mixing)

### Explanation

To explain how I got it to work, lets take an example with choices A, B, C. We would have then the following combinations:

```
A B
A B C
A C
B
B C
C
```

If we take a look closer, we can see some how a pattern. Lets take the result list the first element (A)

```
B
B C
C
---
B
B C
C
```

Hmm, interesting... Now lets take **again** the first element (B)

```
C
---
C
```

It's a simple case but this will happen in any size case.

So I've made the recursion script to get to the end, then adding backwards, the iteration combination and duplicating it with the previous value.

And voila! this is it!

For the final mix where all the elements are demanded, I've made a very similar method, but it **must** contain 1 element of each

#### And it's quite fast!

> Total time for 100000 iterations with 126 combinations: 14.410287857056 seconds

if you find any mistake ping me :D

### Code

https://gist.github.com/MLoureiro/a0ecd1ef477e08b6b83a

Comment: Wow, man, you have solved my problem!!! And your solution is actually right since mine results in the same number of combinations (126) Of course yours is much faster and I'm going to adapt it right away. Thank you so much!

Comment: A while ago I also wrote a recursive algorithm to solve a similar problem. The difference is that mine has the user pass in the number of elements that the outputted combinations should contain (basically it calculates all possible combinations of size r from an input set n). You can find a detailed explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27308438/how-to-cheaply-calculate-all-possible-length-r-combinations-of-n-possible-elem/27308439#27308439